# Machine Specifications - SerializationException after Because executes?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, moq, mspec

I'm having an issue writing a unit test with [Machine.Specifications](https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications), also using [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).  When running the test either via Resharper 8 or with the mspec console running, I get a popup dialog from R# with the following error:

```
[Window Title]
Unit Test Runner

[Main Instruction]
Unit Test Runner failed to run tests


[Content]
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'ASSEMBLY.UNDERTEST, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

[Expanded Information]

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodCallMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoDispatch(Byte[] reqStmBuff, SmuggledMethodCallMessage smuggledMcm, SmuggledMethodReturnMessage& smuggledMrm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.DoTransitionDispatchCallback(Object[] args)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.ISpecificationRunListener.OnFatalError(ExceptionResult exception)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.AggregateRunListener.<>c__DisplayClass17.<OnFatalError>b__16(ISpecificationRunListener listener)
   at Machine.Specifications.Utility.RandomExtensionMethods.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.AggregateRunListener.OnFatalError(ExceptionResult exception)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.AssemblyRunner.Run(Assembly assembly, IEnumerable`1 contexts)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.DefaultRunner.StartRun(IDictionary`2 contextMap)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.DefaultRunner.RunClass(MemberInfo member, Assembly assembly)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.DefaultRunner.RunMember(Assembly assembly, MemberInfo member)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.ISpecificationRunner.RunMember(Assembly assembly, MemberInfo member)
   at Machine.Specifications.Runner.Impl.AppDomainRunner.RunMember(Assembly assembly, MemberInfo member)
   at Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.Runners.RecursiveMSpecTaskRunner.RunContext(ISpecificationRunner runner, Assembly contextAssembly, TaskExecutionNode node)
   at Machine.Specifications.ReSharperRunner.Runners.RecursiveMSpecTaskRunner.ExecuteRecursive(TaskExecutionNode node)
   at JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.StartupTaskRunnerHost.Execute(TaskExecutionNode node)
```

All the tests are marked Inconclusive and nothing appears in the R# session window telling me what happened.  I've tried to create a repo solution but have been unable to do so.  I can step through the code and manually figure out the exception but obviously having this pop up instead makes debugging much more difficult.  Any ideas what is causing the serialization?  It appears a new AppDomain is created, but I can't hook up any events for Resolve Load on the appdomain created.  The Fusion logs show its looking for my assembly being tested in the R# installation folder.  Disabling shadow copies also doesn't have any impact on this.

Any ideas?  I'm using the latest Moq and MSpec from NuGet.

UPDATE:  It doesn't matter if an exception is thrown or not; I am seeing the same behavior if the Because completes without exception, however none of the It statements are executed.

Answer (score 1):

Mspec creates a new AppDomain for each assembly being tested, mostly to support dll.config files. As a side effect all data passed between the spec assembly and the runner must be serialized (remoting does that). Some type that is going to traverse the AppDomain boundary isn't marked with the  SerializableAttribute, hence the exception.

I guess this is likely a custom  exception or a member on that exception as this the only type I can think of that is going to make it across the AppDomain boundary. (Mspec's internal types are all serializable.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into that.  I updated my question though; even if Because executes successfully, the Its are never executed and I get the same exception.  Its interesting though as I have a class I am testing which isn't marked Serializable but its tests work fine.

Comment: The class being tested is not relevant. It's the types crossing the AppDomain boundary, IIRC these are mostly exceptions.

Comment: Ok but as I've re-edited my question, even if the Because clause doesn't throw I end up with the same issue.  So I don't know where any exception would end up being thrown, but I still get a SerializationException.  How can I find out what is causing the issue?

Comment: To tell the truth, I don't know any tools to detect the types in question. Did you see this possibly related question? (ReSharper AppDomain handling was different back then.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326847/spec-fails-when-run-by-mspec-exe-but-passes-when-run-by-td-net

Comment: Especially the part about Thread.CurrentPrincipal is of interest. Does your code use that API?

Comment: No, this test is not changing the threads principal.  Also the tests fail in r# or using the mspec runner.   Does mspec hook an event to the appdomain Resolve event?  at least then it should be possible to output the missing type.

Comment: When you run using `mspec.exe` you may be able to attach a debugger and wait for the `SerializationException`. `mspec.exe --wait` waits 15 seconds for the debugger to attach.

Comment: I ran mspec in a console window and attached the debugger.  I can get it to break on the SerializationException but nothing helpful there, although I can see the exception is raised three times before the process exits.  The exception is occurring on another AppDomain though as I can wire up all the AppDomain events (AssemblyResolve, etc) in the Because and it never fires... so is there another AppDomain created between the Because and execution of the It statements?

Comment: No, there is just one AppDomain for the runner exe and one per spec assembly. Can you share some code or provide a reproduction to us?

Comment: Ok, it turns out a custom principal was being set; however as far as I can tell it is serializable as is the custom identity.

Comment: Can you post a reproduction with the `SerializableAttribute` in place?